# understanding openvpn log + slow rdp

Tags: windows, performance, openvpn, rdp

I am configuring an RDP Server for conection via the internet using OpenVPN.
 Making a direct conection using default RDP port, works like a charm… using the Openvpn tunnel, makes it go slow, really slow some times.
 I have been testing lots of different settings but can't make it work well, lots of pages on internet say that the MTU is the problem, I adjusted the MTU to these settings

```
tun-mtu 1500
mssfix 1400
```

On both the server and clients. But the conection log for client VPN shows..

```
Wed Mar 06 20:39:41 2019 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Wed Mar 06 20:39:41 2019 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Wed Mar 06 20:39:41 2019 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Wed Mar 06 20:39:41 2019 OPTIONS IMPORT: peer-id set

Wed Mar 06 20:39:41 2019 OPTIONS IMPORT: adjusting link_mtu to 1626

Wed Mar 06 20:39:41 2019 OPTIONS IMPORT: data channel crypto options modified
```

Is the MTU changing ? where can I adjust this ?
Thanks, and any info is welcome… please, don’t mind the crappy English…